# How to extract and use data from JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm new to Python. Now I have a JSON file. I need first read the file in Python and then do something (make a two way table, etc.) with it.
I was able to do this:

```py
import json
with open('DrateLspan.json') as f:
    file = json.load(f)
for i in file:
    print(i['Year'])
```

However, since I need extract the data from JSON and do something more, I do not want to stop at the "print" step. I tried `ye = file['Year']` but it shows "string indices must be integers, not str". Can anyone help me with this? I want use the data in the JSON file.

Below this the first several lines of my JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "Year": 2015,
    "Race": "All Races",
    "Sex": "Both Sexes",
    "Average Life Expectancy (Years)": "",
    "Age-adjusted Death Rate": 733.1
  },
  {
    "Year": 2014,
    "Race": "All Races",
    "Sex": "Both Sexes",
    "Average Life Expectancy (Years)": 78.9,
    "Age-adjusted Death Rate": 724.6
  },
  {
    "Year": 2013,
    "Race": "All Races",
    "Sex": "Both Sexes",
    "Average Life Expectancy (Years)": 78.8,
    "Age-adjusted Death Rate": 731.9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

The json file is array of dicts. so you need to iterate over that list and the access each of the dicts and the `year` attribute. To collect all the years you can collect that to a list.

If you don't duplicates you can use a `set`

```
import json

with open('test.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    year = []
    for item in data:
        year.append(item['Year'])
    print(year)
    #uncomment the below line to remove duplicates
    year = set(year)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. But the result was only correct when I use >print(year). I got a list of years. However, if I just use >year, I only got one result which is 1900. So confused. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you might have just gotten a bit mixed up on some variable names. You are trying to do:

```py
year = file["Year"]
```

But the `file` variable is the list not the individual item. You probably meant:

```py
year = i["Year"]
```

Something like this should work just fine:

```py
import json

with open(filename) as json_file:
    all_data = json.load(json_file)

for entry in all_data:
    year = entry["Year"]
    # Do something with year
```

One thing I find helpful to avoid confusing situations like this is to always name my variables something specific. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I tried. It worked but it only shows one result, which is 1900. I expect there would be a list of years. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Sounds like you might be a bit confused about how for loops work. I would check out one of these resources: [w3 schools on for loops](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) or [geek for geeks on loops](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/loops-in-python/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Panda, which does the job to organize your data conveniently.
Look at how easy it can be:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('json.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
    print(df)
```

Which will create (and print) something like:

```
   Year       Race         Sex Average Life Expectancy (Years)  Age-adjusted Death Rate
0  2015  All Races  Both Sexes                                                    733.1
1  2014  All Races  Both Sexes                            78.9                    724.6
2  2013  All Races  Both Sexes                            78.8                    731.9
```

Then you can access your data in multiple ways:

- Individual item: `print(df.loc[0,'Year'])`
- By row: `print(df.loc[0])`
- By column: `df['Year']`

It's very flexible. If you need a quick start, this might be a valuable [tutorial](https://pythonhow.com/accessing-dataframe-columns-rows-and-cells/)